# Alignment in table depends on length of header

Tags: tables, tabularx

When I delete the header "General variables used in the header" in the code (or any long text), the two columns overlap like this:

**Current output:**

[image]

**Current code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm},bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}      

  \usepackage{amsmath}                      
  \usepackage{mathtools} 
  \usepackage{tabularx}                     
  \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}   

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lp{6cm}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{\hskip-1.2in Definition}   \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{General variables used in the model} \\
        $K$ & \hskip-1.2in Fixed amount of money need to start production \\
        $s$ & \hskip-1.2in Baseline quality of the good (normalized to 1) \\
        $n$ & \hskip-1.2in Number of people \\
        $\pi_1, \pi_2, \Pi$ & \hskip-1.2in%
 \vtop{\hsize=3.5in Profits of the entrepreneur in the first period ($\pi_1$),%
 in the second period ($\pi_2$) and total profits $\Pi = \pi_1 + \pi_1$)} \\
        $P_r$ & \hskip-1.2in $P_r$ is the regular price \\
        $\alpha$ & \hskip-1.2in $\alpha$ is specific for Case 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
     \vskip.1in\par
     {\textit{Note}: This table....
        \textit{Source}: Source to be inserted}
    \caption{Definition of variables}
    \label{table_alm}
\end{table}

  \end{document}
```

But when I keep the header, the table looks okay. Ideally I would like to remove the title and still keep the output like this:

**Desired output:**

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you insert negative spacing such as `\hskip-1.2in`  then this is an explicit instruction for text to over-print. If you do not want this to cause over-printing, why is it there?

Comment: I reused the code from a table where I needed to over-print.

Comment: yes but why add that and then ask a question asking why the columns over print without even mentioning you have over an inch or negative space in each cell?

Comment: I thought that `\hskip-1.2in` on each row would make the column to the right align properly. Didn't know that this would make the two columns overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{table}[!htb] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lp{6cm}}\toprule
        \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{ Definition}   \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{General variables used in the model}} \\
        $K$ & Fixed amount of money need to start production \\
        $s$ & Baseline quality of the good (normalized to 1) \\
        $n$ & Number of people \\
        $\pi_1, \pi_2, \Pi$ & 
            Profits of the entrepreneur in the first period ($\pi_1$),%
            in the second period ($\pi_2$) and total profits ($\Pi = \pi_1 + \pi_1$) \\
        $P_r$ & $P_r$ is the regular price \\
        $\alpha$ & $\alpha$ is specific for Case 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip
    \textit{Note}: This table....
    \textit{Source}: Source to be inserted
    \caption{Definition of variables}\label{table_alm}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Using `tabularx` with   `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}\toprule`
makes more sense:

[image]

And without the second line:

```
    \begin{tabular}{lp{6cm}}\toprule
        \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Definition}\\\midrule
        $K$ & Fixed amount of money need to start production \\
        ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! When I remove `\textbf{General variables used in the model}`, there is a gap between the mid rule and the first variable. I tried adding `\vskip`under `\multicolumn}` to remove the vertical space, but the program crashes. How do I remove the white space?

Comment: I cannot see it. Look at the end of my edited answer

Comment: Got it now! Deleted `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{General variables used in the model}} \\` and used the tabularx-option. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of all `\vskip` and `\hskip` instructions and simply use a two-column `tabularx` environment. By the way, **bold-facing** is much more effective if it's used sparingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Definition}   \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{General variables used in the model} \\[1ex]
        $K$ & Fixed amount of money need to start production \\
        $s$ & Baseline quality of the good (normalized to 1) \\
        $n$ & Number of people \\
        $\pi_1, \pi_2, \Pi$ & Profits of the entrepreneur in the first period ($\pi_1$), 
            profits in the second period~($\pi_2$), and total profits 
            ($\Pi = \pi_1 + \pi_1$) \\
        $P_r$ & $P_r$ is the regular price \\
        $\alpha$ & $\alpha$ is specific for Case 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

    \bigskip
    \textit{Note}: This table \dots 

    \textit{Source}: Source to be inserted
    \caption{Definition of variables}
    \label{table_alm}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```